# Mailjet API - When adding new contact to list confirmation email not sent

Tags: mailjet

I'm using `/:id/managecontact` endpoint to add new emails to list. Emails is added but no confirmation/opt-in email is being sent to that email.

Is it not posible to do that with API calls or there has to be made some additional call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding contacts directly through the API, the email address is directly inserted in the list, without confirmation email. To generate an opt-in message, you should use the subscription widget -> https://www.mailjet.com/docs/widget

Feel free to open a [support ticket](https://www.mailjet.com/support/ticket), should you have additional questions.